# MySQL using GROUP BY after multiple UNIONS

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct, union

I have a fairly complex MySQL Query with multiple `UNION` statements. I am trying to eliminate duplicates from the final output, but not all the columns are identical (including the ID). So I want to use `GROUP BY` on the 'name' column to eliminate entries with the same name.  This is for a map mashup of a number of other map layers.  Some of the place markers appear on multiple layers (i.e. a restaurant may appear on the 'dining' layer, and the 'bars' layer, and the 'Home Cooking' layer, each with a different ID).

Each `UNION SELECT` statement produces only one row that has the place's 'name', but by the end, after all the `UNION`s have run, I have multiple entries for the same place. So I feel like I need to somehow process the `GROUP BY` on all the data after every `UNION` has occurred.

I will try to illustrate with a simplified version of the statement...

```
(
    SELECT l.id AS lid, m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
    FROM layertable 
    INNER JOIN markertable 
    ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
    WHERE l.id='66' 
    ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place AND Eatery
)
UNION
(
    SELECT l.id AS lid, m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
    FROM layertable 
    INNER JOIN markertable 
    ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
    WHERE l.id='82' 
    ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place AND Eatery
)
UNION
(
    SELECT l.id AS lid, m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
    FROM layertable 
    INNER JOIN markertable 
    ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
    WHERE l.id='91' 
    ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place
)

ORDER BY markername ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Results look something like...

```
| lid | markername | mid | mlayer               |
=================================================
| 66  | Joes Place | 10  | ["66","82","91"]     |
| 82  | Joes Place | 10  | ["66","82","91"]     |
| 91  | Joes Place | 10  | ["66","82","91"]     |
| 66  | Eatery     | 11  | ["66","82"]          |
| 82  | Eatery     | 11  | ["66","82"]          |
```

What I want is...

```
| lid | markername | mid | mlayer               |
=================================================
| 91  | Joes Place | 10  | ["66","82","91"]     |
| 82  | Eatery     | 11  | ["66","82"]          |
```

`DISTINCT` doesn't seem to work, because the records are not completely identical.

I have tried to put `GROUP BY markername` before and after `ORDER BY` but I get a syntax error message either way.  Applying it within the individual `SELECT`S doesn't help because each table will only have one instance of the place anyway.

So, to reiterate my question: 
How to apply `GROUP BY` to the total list, after `UNION` and output just the uniquely named places?
OR is there some other way to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need the id values why are you trying to discard all but one for each with a group by? If you don't, why are you selecting them?

Comment: Also, why are you using UNION when `WHERE l.id IN ('66', '82', '91')` would be clearer and possibly faster?

Comment: This is to display a list of the map markers below the map itself.  I don't need that list to show Joes Place 3 times.  Just one.  The map itself already eliminates the duplicate markers, but the list, out of the box, does not.

Comment: Why not do a query on the union results? `SELECT * FROM (<union query>) GROUP BY markername`

Comment: Actually no, it's because `lid` is distinct on each row. Just don't select that field. Remove `l.id AS lid,` from each query. If you're not interested in their unique values I assume that means you aren't actually interested in them at all. So don't select them and you won't have duplicates.

Comment: Anthony, Your first comment was the solution for me. Just had to make sure the the derived table had an alias, but that worked. Thanks.

Comment: I'm working with existing code...try to modify it as little as possible.  Much of it is generated via php based on various options and settings. Anthony's comment fixed the problem while only requiring a couple of extra lines and characters.

Comment: See my answer. Glad that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `GROUP BY` of all of the results, like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT l.id AS lid, m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
    FROM layertable AS l
    INNER JOIN markertable 
    ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
    WHERE l.id='66' 
    ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place AND Eatery
)
UNION
(
    SELECT l.id AS lid, m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
    FROM layertable AS l
    INNER JOIN markertable 
    ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
    WHERE l.id='82' 
    ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place AND Eatery
)
UNION
(
    SELECT l.id AS lid, m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
    FROM layertable AS l
    INNER JOIN markertable 
    ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
    WHERE l.id='91' 
    ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place
)

ORDER BY markername ASC
LIMIT 10
) AS makernames
GROUP BY makername
```

Or you could just leave out the parts that are causing the results to be non-unique. Like:

```
(
    SELECT m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
    FROM layertable AS l
    INNER JOIN markertable 
    ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
    WHERE l.id='66' 
    ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place AND Eatery
)
UNION
(
    SELECT m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
    FROM layertable AS l
    INNER JOIN markertable 
    ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
    WHERE l.id='82' 
    ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place AND Eatery
)
UNION
(
    SELECT m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
    FROM layertable AS l
    INNER JOIN markertable 
    ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
    WHERE l.id='91' 
    ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place
)

ORDER BY markername ASC
LIMIT 10
```

You don't need to have `l.id` in the `SELECT` clause for it to work in the `WHERE` clause. And I assume that if you are willing to lose the `lid` on some rows just to have only one row per `makername` that that means you don't actually need `lid` at all in the results.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a group by and max(id)

```
  select max(lid), markername, mid, mlayer 
  from (


  (
      SELECT l.id AS lid, m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
      FROM layertable 
      INNER JOIN markertable 
      ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
      WHERE l.id='66' 
      ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place AND Eatery
  )
  UNION
  (
      SELECT l.id AS lid, m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
      FROM layertable 
      INNER JOIN markertable 
      ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
      WHERE l.id='82' 
      ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place AND Eatery
  )
  UNION
  (
      SELECT l.id AS lid, m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
      FROM layertable 
      INNER JOIN markertable 
      ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
      WHERE l.id='91' 
      ## RESULT INCLUDES Joes Place
  )

  ORDER BY markername ASC
  LIMIT 10 
  ) t
  group by markername, mid, mlayer
```

Comment: This one also works for me. However, I think Anthony's comment is a better fit for my situation.

Comment: This one is more portable and future proof; other databases and the default configuration of recent MySQL releases, do not allow a `group by` with fields that are neither grouped on or aggregated.

Comment: @cvc the solution provided by Anthony's don't work in most recent version of mysql (5.7)  .. Because the use of group by in precense of select column without aggregation function not mentioned  in group by is deprecated  in SQL the resul for the not aggregated  column is unpredictable and  as  tell before .. don't work in more recente mysql version ..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all with one query:

```
SELECT max(l.id) AS lid, m.markername AS markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
FROM layertable 
INNER JOIN markertable 
ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
  WHERE l.id in ('66','82','91')
GROUP BY m.markername, m.id, m.layer
```

Answer (score 0):

(this should be a comment, but its a bit long)

> because the records are not completely identical

Then you NEED TO BE A LOT MORE SPECIFIC ABOUT WHAT YOU MEAN BY DUPLICATES. In your example you have extracted the MAX(l.id) - is that your intention?

Why are you using a UNION here? You could just...

```
SELECT MAX(lid), markername, mid, mlayer
FROM ( 
  SELECT l.id AS lid, m.markername, m.id AS mid, m.layer AS mlayer
  FROM layertable 
  INNER JOIN markertable 
  ON m.layer LIKE Concat('%"',l.id,'"%') 
  WHERE l.id IN ('91', '82', '66')
  LIMIT 10
) AS ilv
GROUP BY markername, mid, mlayer
```

Using LIKE is a JOIN is horrible and implies your data is not normalized. Why are the integer values being quoted in your query?

(note that the subselect may be redundant / speeding things up or slowing them down depending on the distribution of your data and the indexes available).

Don't you think you should be organizing map data around geospatial indexing?